# Display last modified date on a Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, last-modified

I was wondering if anyone knows an effective way of displaying the last modified date on a Wordpress site.

I'm not interested in the last modified date of a single post or page, but in a date (and maybe time) that shows the last time ANY modification was made on a site.

For example:

- I modify the "Hello World" post on 15/09/18
- I modify the "Sample page" page on 16/09/18
- The "My last modified" displays "16/09/18" on the "Hello World" post and
  also on the "Sample page" page.

I'm aware of the [the_modified_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_modified_date) and the [get_the_modified_date()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_modified_date) functions, but I'd like to **effectively** show the latest from all of the modified content (pages, posts, custom post types, etc.)

Thank you for your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could query the most recently updated posts and pages, then pull out the updated date from there. Try something like this.

```
$recently_updated_posts = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'      => array('any'),
    'posts_per_page' => 1
    'orderby'        => 'modified',
    'no_found_rows'  => true, // speed up query when we don't need pagination
));
```

Then, you can use the `$recently_updated_posts` in the standard WordPress loop and have access to `the_modified_date()` and the `get_the_modified_date()` functions.

Comment: Thank you, this is a technically correct answer - but I'm not sure if it's effective. What do you think - wouldn't it be more effective, if I created some form of custom data, and hooked in on the "Update" action of a post/page, so it updates my custom data with the "last modified" data? I could call that data with a MySQL call, knowing that it's always the "latest".

Comment: Check out the WordPress Transient API. You can run the query once and store it in a transient. You can then use a hook when a post has been updated to clear the cache.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

You can of course store the value using SQL, but I tend to avoid doing this if I can in WordPress.

Comment: Now that’s what I call an idea! Thank you! :)